# Will golang garbage collecting channel of pointers when it's dequeued from channel?

Tags: go

If I have something like this:

```
requests := make(chan *RequestStruct, 1000 * 1000)
responses := make(chan *ResponseStruct, 1000 * 1000)
```

If the all `requests` and `responses` already dequeued/consumed, those pointers that previously was there would someday will be garbage collected right? (or it won't because nobody ever set it to nil on the channel?)

Comment: If there are no other pointers to those structs, they will be GC'd, eventually.

Comment: GC collects everything that is collectable. The fact that some things have been inside a channel or that some things are pointers has no influence whatsoever on this fact.

Comment: ok cool, one less suspect of the memory leak then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channels are implemented in `runtime/chan.go`.  Reading from a buffered channel is implemented by the function `chanrecv`, which does the following:

```
qp := chanbuf(c, c.recvx)
typedmemmove(c.elemtype, ep, qp)
typedmemclr(c.elemtype, qp)
```

The element that is stored in the channel is cleared by the `typedmemclr`, and will therefore not prevent the pointed-at element from being garbage-collected.

Comment: That is quite interesting! So if the only reference to your object is the pointer inside the channel the GC might clear the object and when you dereference the object-pointer you might see that it is nil. To circumvent this you might pass the struct through the channel or keep it inside a global variable to have a reference that the GC will respect. Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: I don't think that's the case.  If the pointer is stored in the channel, the object cannot be GCd.